# How to Update only the year (yyyy) in the datetime data type using SQL Query? with out dateadd function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

```
2006-01-01 20:00:00.000
2006-01-01 20:01:00.000
2006-01-01 20:02:00.000
2006-01-01 20:03:00.000
2006-01-01 20:04:00.000
2006-01-01 20:01:00.000
2006-01-01 20:01:00.000
2006-01-01 20:01:00.000
```

and I want

```
2004-01-01 20:00:00.000
2004-01-01 20:01:00.000
2004-01-01 20:02:00.000
2004-01-01 20:03:00.000
2004-01-01 20:04:00.000
2004-01-01 20:01:00.000
2004-01-01 20:01:00.000
2004-01-01 20:01:00.000
```

Comment: What code have your tried yet? Please first show us some effort then expect us to answer the question.

Comment: `UPDATE yourtable SET yourdate = DATE_ADD(yourdate, INTERVAL -2 YEAR)`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col_date=DATE_FORMAT(col_date,'2004-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

for changing only year:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2004-%m-%d');
```